# How do I use .apply(func) with a conditional function (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Pd series

```
    count   area    volume      formula     quantity
0   1.0     22       NaN       count         1.0
1   1.0     15       NaN       count         1.0
2   1.0     1.4      NaN       area          1.4
3   1.0     0.6       10       volume        100
```

The quantity column is based on the value in the formula column via a lookup e.g. row(0) is "count" so it is 1, row(2) is "area" so it's 1.4

For this I have a the following formula

```
Merged['quantity']=Merged.apply(lambda x: x[x['QuantityFormula']] , axis=1)
```

However quantity for volume is a calculated field: volume * 10. I've written a function to calculate both

```
def func(x):
    if x[x['QuantityFormula']] == Volume:
        return volume * 10
    else:
        return x[x['QuantityFormula']]
   
    
df['Classification'] = Merged['QuantityFormula'].apply(func)
```

However I get the following error

```
Error: string indices must be integers
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer

```
def func(row):
    if row['QuantityFormula'] == 'Volume':
        return row['Volume'] * 10
    return row[row['quantity']]

Merged['Ans'] = Merged.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Comment: what is **QuantityFormula** ?

Comment: It is a string, I am matching the strings in this row with the table headers and taking the value of the row. In the case of volume it needs to be multiplied by 10 hence the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x['volume']*10 if x['formula'] == 'volume' else x['quantity'], axis=1)

print(df)

   count  area  volume formula  quantity    ans
0    1.0  22.0     NaN   count       1.0    1.0
1    1.0  15.0     NaN   count       1.0    1.0
2    1.0   1.4     NaN    area       1.4    1.4
3    1.0   0.6    10.0  volume     100.0  100.0
```

Using an explicit function, you can do:

```
def func(row):
    if row['formula'] == 'volume':
        return row['volume'] * 10
    return row['quantity']

df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it through a function like the one in the example? As there will several others formulas coming in the future?

Comment: @Jimmy3421 please checknow

Comment: I modified it to the below, it works thanks.

def func(row):
    if row['QuantityFormula'] == 'Volume':
        return row['Volume'] * 10
    return row[row['quantity']]

Merged['Ans'] = Merged.apply(func, axis=1)

Comment: Thanks that worked, I modified it a little for my case

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookup:

```
import numpy as np

s = df['formula'].str.lower()
m = s.eq('volume')

idx, cols = pd.factorize(s)

df['quantity'] = (df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
                  *  np.where(m, 10, 1)
                  )
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it through a function like the one in the example? As there will several others formulas coming in the future?

Comment: @Jimmy3421 yes, but it's not advisable, `apply` on `axis=1` is very slow compared to vectorization